# Cada palabra dentro de un div

Tags: javascript

Estoy implementando un spellcheker(corrector de palabras), tengo un contenedor donde cada nueva palabra escrita se coloca en un div nuevo, en lugar de colocarla como texto ordinario.

Estoy poniendo cada palabra en un div, para que se despliegue las sugerencias de palabras, es necesario esto? o lo puedo poner en span ? o en ninguna etiqueta?

Con div logre el despliegue de sugerencias, **cuando intento con span NO funciona**.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Para ver la funcionalidad, escriba cualquier palabra y presione la barra espaciadora

```js
let written = '';
document.getElementById('parent').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {

  written += String.fromCharCode(e.which);

  if (e.which === 32) {
    let newDivWord = document.createElement('div');

    newDivWord.appendChild(document.createTextNode(written));
    newDivWord.classList.add('root');
    newDivWord.id = document.getElementById('parent').childElementCount + 1;
    document.getElementById('parent').appendChild(newDivWord);
    console.log(document.getElementById('parent'));
    written = "";
  }
})
```

```css
#parent>div {
  border-color: yellow;
  float: left;
}

.root {
  padding-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" contenteditable=true style="border: black 2px solid; height:200px">
  <div class="root" id="1">Qué</div>
  <div class="root" id="2">es</div>
  <div class="root" id="3">Lorem</div>
  <div class="root" id="4">Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

deberia ser borrado el texto escrito que no esta dentro del div nuevo?

**La funcionalidad futura de mi problema seria:**, pero si me ayudan les agradeceria infinito.

El texto *Que es Lorem Ipsum* si tipeo 'hola' antes de lorem deberia quedar 'Que es hola Lorem Ipsum', en un div propio.

El texto *Que es Lorem Ipsum* si tipeo 'hola' despues de Ipsum deberia quedar 'Que es Lorem Ipsum hola', en un div propio.

El texto *Que es Lorem Ipsum* si tipeo 'hola' antes de 'QUE' deberia quedar 'hola Que es Lorem Ipsum hola', en un div propio.

El texto *Que es Lorem Ipsum* si tipeo 'hola' antes de 'sum' deberia quedar 'hola Que es Lorem Iphola sum hola', se crearia un div para Iphola y sum quedaria otro div.

**Lo que necesito ahora en el presente:** quiero que no se repita la palabra nueva, una de ellas es la escritura del texto normal, y la otra repeticion es la creacion del nuevo div, y deberia añadirse al final el div nuevo.

Comment: No termino de comprender cuál es el problema que estás teniendo o que quieres resolver. ¿Quieres borrar la palabra que se escribió? ¿No quieres ponerla al final? ¿qué hacer si la palabra rompe una palabra ya existente?

Comment: si rompe una palabra existente deberian crearse tres divs con tres palabras, pero esa seria otra funcionalidad, por el momento solo pretendo que se agregue al final la palabra nueva en un div.

Comment: ¿Y se borra de la otra palabra/div? Por ejemplo: si pongo el cursor justo antes de "Lorem", escribo "hola" y pulso la barra espaciadora, ¿cuál debería ser el resultado: "Qué es Lorem Ipsum hola" o "Qué es hola Lorem Ipsum hola"? Y si es lo segundo, el primer "hola" iría en el mismo `div` que "Lorem" o en otro propio? ¿Y el segundo "hola"?

Comment: al primer párrafo le falta una conclusión antes de la coma, sera 'DIV' ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una cosa que puedes hacer es usar `getSelection()` para obtener el nodo de texto activo, y a partir de ahí editar su contenido (con `getSelection().focusNode().textContent`).

Por ejemplo, la siguiente demo elimina la palabra que se insertó, pero tiene un par de problemas: 1) deja el espacio en blanco (creo que es por el tipo de evento, pero he realizado pruebas con `keyup` y falla, tengo que ver por qué es); y 2) mueve el cursor al principio del nodo de texto (puede no ser un problema si la palabra se inserta al principio, pero es algo inconveniente si es al final).

Lo dejo por si te sirve de base mientras intento mejorarlo:

```js
let written = '';
document.getElementById('parent').addEventListener('keypress', function(e) {

  // guardamos la palabra
  var palabra = written;
  written += String.fromCharCode(e.which);

  if (e.which === 32) {
  
    // seleccionamos el nodo activo
    var sel = window.getSelection();
    // eliminamos la palabra recien escrita
    sel.focusNode.textContent = sel.focusNode.textContent.replace(palabra, "");
    
    let newDivWord = document.createElement('div');

    newDivWord.appendChild(document.createTextNode(written));
    newDivWord.classList.add('root');
    newDivWord.id = document.getElementById('parent').childElementCount + 1;
    document.getElementById('parent').appendChild(newDivWord);
    console.log(document.getElementById('parent'));
    written = "";
  }
})
```

```css
#parent>div {
  border-color: yellow;
  float: left;
}

.root {
  padding-right: 2px;
}
```

```html
<div id="parent" contenteditable=true style="border: black 2px solid; height:200px">
  <div class="root" id="1">Qué</div>
  <div class="root" id="2">es</div>
  <div class="root" id="3">Lorem</div>
  <div class="root" id="4">Ipsum</div>
</div>
```

Comment: no puedo poner el cursor en medio de un div

Answer (score 0):

Acabo de hacer una validación ejecutando tu código, porque tengo una necesidad similar para crear un elemento que me facilite agregar dinámicamente familias de palabras claves.
Noté que si trato de editar alguna palabra existente, ésta es reemplazada y adicionalmente los cambios son agregados al final. **imagino que no es el comportamiento deseado**.

> Texto inicial: Qué es Loren Ipsum
>   edito como: Qu**eda como** Loren Ipsum
>   El contenedor muestra: Quda como es Loren Ipsum da como
>   Y el cursor se mantiene dentro del primer contenedor,

Con dev tools inspeccioné los elementos y encuentro que la cadena `Quda como` permanece en el primer div y se agregan dos nuevos al final **<div class="root">da</div>** y **<div class="root">como</div>** De modo que tu código necesita atender la posibilidad de que los contenedores existentes sean editados y que eventualmente se edite entre dos de ellos.

En cuanto a tu pregunta, me parece que entre contenedores sólo pueden haber espacios y o caracteres de puntuación (separadores) puesto que tu interés, supongo, debe ser atrapar las palabras. De modo que si eventualmente quedara algún texto libre se debiera insertar en un contenedor en lugar de borrarlo.

Comment: por el momento me ayudaria que se añadiera al final, pero que no se escriba dos veces

Comment: Hola estoy en el chat. Entré a buscarte